# Euro Rail Pass in non-native country

Tags: france, eurail

Can I get a Euro Rail Pass in France considering that I haven't applied for it in my native country i.e. India?

Comment: what does "applied for it in my native country" mean exactly?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, but you may have less options and pay more:

[www.wikihow.com](http://www.wikihow.com/Buy-a-Eurail-Pass):

> Visit a Eurail Aid Office if you need help with your Eurail Pass, or
> if you arrive in Europe without having purchased a pass. Eurail Aid
> Offices are almost always located within large train stations; consult
> the list at //www.eurail.com/eurail-aid-offices to find one in your
> country of origin or destination.
>
> If you cannot find a Eurail Aid
> Office in your country, Eurail recommends asking for help at the
> international ticket window in a large train station.
>
> The only Eurail
> passes available for purchase in Europe are: single-country passes to
> Romania, Portugal, Norway, Italy, Ireland, Hungary, Greece and
> Croatia; multiple-country passes for Hungary-Romania, Greece-Italy,
> Austria-Hungary, Croatia-Slovenia-Hungary or Austria-Croatia-Slovenia;
> Eurail Select Passes, and the Eurail Global Pass.

Eurail.com has a [list with offices](http://www.eurail.com/plan-your-trip/travel-resources/eurail-aid-offices) where you can buy the pass but they say:

> Online Eurail.Com prices are on average 20% lower than the prices
> charged at European train stations. Not all Eurail passes are for sale
> in Europe.

Answer (score 4):

From my experience, you can.  I'm from New Zealand, and bought my 10 day Eurail pass in Luxembourg last year.  I used it in Luxembourg, Germany and Poland, but could have used it in any of the other Eurail zone countries.